# How to get information about host rather than the Container utilizing the python psutil library?

Tags: python, docker, psutil

I am creating a system monitoring tool currently and my application is inside a container. I want to be able to use psutil to retrieve my host machines details(running processes, CPU utilization and memory utilization rather than the containers running processes. Below is monitor.py file that does the info-gathering and my docker file. Im pretty new to container and stuff so feel free to rip into me if I am missing something. Thanks.

monitor.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import psutil

import time
from subprocess import call
from prettytable import PrettyTable


def add(cmd):
    """
    Input is command to added to the queue
    Returns a confirmation of item being added to queue. 

    """
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='rabbitmq'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)
    channel.basic_publish(
        exchange='',
        routing_key='task_queue',
        body=cmd,
        properties=pika.BasicProperties(
            delivery_mode=2,  # make message persistent
        ))
    connection.close()
    return " [x] Sent: %s" % cmd

def getRunningProcesses():
    proc = []
    # get the pids from last which mostly are user processes
    for pid in psutil.pids()[-200:]:
        try:
            p = psutil.Process(pid)
            # trigger cpu_percent() the first time which leads to return of 0.0
            p.cpu_percent()
            proc.append(p)

        except Exception as e:
            pass

    # sort by cpu_percent
    top = {}
    time.sleep(0.1)
    for p in proc:
        # trigger cpu_percent() the second time for measurement
        top[p] = p.cpu_percent() / psutil.cpu_count()

    top_list = sorted(top.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    top10 = top_list
    top10.reverse()
    top10 = str(top10)
    print(top10)
    try:
        add(top10)
    except Exception:
        pass
    
    return top10

print(getRunningProcesses())
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install pika && \
    pip3 install apscheduler && \
    pip3 install PrettyTable && \
    pip3 install psutil && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

app.py(my flask server)

```
from flask import Flask
import pika
import monitor

#!/usr/bin/python3
""" Demonstrating Flask, using APScheduler. """

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from flask import Flask

def sensor():
    try:
        print(monitor.getRunningProcesses())
        print("POLLING ")
    except Exception:
        print("monitor fail")
        pass

sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.add_job(sensor,'interval',minutes=.2)
sched.start()
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'testing'


@app.route('/add-job/<cmd>')
def add(cmd):
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='rabbitmq'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)
    channel.basic_publish(
        exchange='',
        routing_key='task_queue',
        body=cmd,
        properties=pika.BasicProperties(
            delivery_mode=2,  # make message persistent
        ))
    connection.close()
    return " [x] Sent: %s" % cmd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=4200)
```

Comment: Docker specifically isolates the container from the other processes on the host, to the level that PID 1 on the host is different from PID 1 in the container. Your program sounds like it will be much more at home running directly on the host machine.

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks for the response. I sorta started using Docker for this as I was utilizing RabbitMq to help deal with handling my constant polling of the host system and that getting started was deployed as container so I attempted to integrate my app for easy deployment. If I wanted to just run locally what are some things I should look into to making the application portable and easy to run for people other than myself. Thanks!